# format of date using to_date function

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which use a date 
I work with oracle

but I have a problem in format of date

when I run my query I have an error

this my query test:

```
select NUM_REQUEST, 
 from REQUEST_TEST

where REQUEST_DATE between TO_DATE('Thu Nov 07 00:00:00 CET 2013','MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a')  and TO_DATE('Mon Dec 23 00:00:00 CET 2013','MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a'))
```

I have an error in foramt of date using to_date function

when I try with this query and I have a correct result

```
select NUM_REQUEST, 
 from REQUEST_TEST

where REQUEST_DATE between to_timestamp_tz('Thu Nov 07 00:00:00 CET 2013','Dy Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZR yyyy')  and to_timestamp_tz('Mon Dec 23 00:00:00 CET 2013','Dy Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZR yyyy'))
```

but when I test in my application with :

```
  String sqlQuery = "select NUM_REQUEST, from REQUEST_TEST" + 

  " where REQUEST_DATE between to_timestamp_tz('Thu Nov 07 00:00:00 CET 2013','Dy Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZR yyyy')  and to_timestamp_tz('Mon Dec 23 00:00:00 CET 2013','Dy Mon dd  hh24:mi:ss TZR yyyy')) "; 
Query query = this.getSession().createSQLQuery(sqlQuery);
```

I have this error :

```
ORA-01846: ce n'est pas un jour de semaine valide
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query
```

I have for example in my column **REQUEST_DATE** this data **29-NOV-13** and when I edit this column I have this format for example : **friday, 29 Novembre 2013 00:00:00 o'clock CET**

Comment: The string that holds your date (`Thu Nov...`) is completely different to the [date format model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212) you're providing to the same function (`MM/DD/...`). Not really surprising that it's complaining. You may need to be working with `timestamp` rather than `date` if you're passing in a time zone. You seem to have a trailing comma on the first line as well. It's generally useful to show the actual error you get.

Comment: thank you for your response, I want to know the format corresponding to this date Thu Nov 07 00:00:00 CET 2013

Comment: Off topic, but please consider to accept and/or upvote answers to your questions if they help you. That would help others to detect if given answers are useful or not.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, your date format must match your date string. Have a look at [Oracle Datetime Format Elements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF51079) for all possible elements.
Also, since there is a timezone in your string you need to cast it to [timestamp datatype and not date](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:5011677391274). So, you need to use [TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions214.htm#i999847) function.

So, to answer you question it should be something like this.

```
to_timestamp_tz('Thu Nov 07 00:00:00 CET 2013','Dy Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZR yyyy')
```

Looks like your language setting is french. So you need to supply the month/day accordingly.

```
to_timestamp_tz('Jeu. Nov. 07 00:00:00 CET 2013','Dy Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZR yyyy')
```

or you should explicitly change the language to English, which you can do in the function call itself.

```
to_timestamp_tz('Thu Nov 07 00:00:00 CET 2013',
                'Dy Mon dd hh24:mi:ss TZR yyyy',
                'nls_date_language = ENGLISH')
```

Comment: +1, I did not see your answer until I posted mine. Will leave it as it has slightly different information but yours is more complete.

Answer (score 0):

The closest one I can think of would be:

```
select NUM_REQUEST, 
 from REQUEST_TEST
 where REQUEST_DATE Between TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('Thu Nov 07 00:00:00 CET 2013','DY MON DD  HH24:MI:SS TZR YYYY' )  And TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('Mon Dec 23 00:00:00 CET 2013','DY MON DD  HH24:MI:SS TZR YYYY')
```

Be careful with the `month abbreviations`, as they depend on your locale language settings. For example, December is `Dec` in English but `Dic` in Spanish.

**Update**: your problem with ORA-01846 is related as well to your locale language settings. You need to use the abbreviation corresponding to your language. For example, I guess that for French the abbreviation for `Friday` (`Vendredi` in French) would be `Ven`.

Comment: I updated my answer regarding your week day problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need this. And I believe you get this date format from UNIX.
You can also try formatting the date from Unix if so.

```
select to_timestamp_tz('Thu Nov 07 00:00:00 EDT 2013','Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS TZD YYYY') from dual;
```